# Wrong output when using Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my Script

```
SELECT a.PLUCODE as [Code],a.ITEMNAME as [Item],  
    sum(a.janQTY) AS [2012 QTY] ,sum(a.janAmt) AS [2012 AMT],  
    sum(b.janQTY) AS [2013 QTY] ,sum(b.janAmt) AS [ ]
FROM 2012_Table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 2013_Table b  ON a.PLUCODE=b.PLUCODE 
WHERE a.CATEGORY='Category1'  
GROUP BY a.PLUCODE,a.ITEMNAME 
ORDER BY a.PLUCODE
```

OUTPUT is

```
Code Item     2012 QTY     2012 AMT     2013 QTY  2013 AMT  
0312 ItemOne  67           837,500      21        262,500
```

My output in [2012 QTY] and [2012 AMT] is correct, but on [2013 QTY] and [2013 AMT] is wrong it should be 1 for qty and 12,500  only for the amount, can somebody help me what is the correct script for this.

Comment: That's probably going to be difficult without some sample data that shows the alleged discrepancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a Cartesian result.  21 entries @ 12,500 = 262,500.  You probably need to prequery each on its own merit, then left-join.  I am going on an assumption that the 2013 table is the same structure as 2012.

```
select
      PQ1.PLUCode,
      PQ1.Item,
      PQ1.[2012 QTY],
      PQ1.[2012 AMT],
      PQ2.[2013 QTY],
      PQ2.[2013 AMT]
   from
      ( select a.PLUCode, 
               a.ItemName as [Item],
               sum( a.JanQty ) as [2012 QTY],
               sum( a.JanAmt ) as [2012 AMT]
           from 2012_Table a
           where a.Category = 'Category1'
           group by a.PLUCode, a.ItemName
           order by a.PLUCode ) PQ1
      LEFT JOIN
      ( select b.PLUCode, 
               b.ItemName as [Item],
               sum( b.JanQty ) as [2013 QTY],
               sum( b.JanAmt ) as [2013 AMT]
           from 2013_Table b
           where b.Category = 'Category1'
           group by b.PLUCode, b.ItemName
           order by b.PLUCode ) PQ2
         ON PQ1.PLUCode = PQ2.PLUCode
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work better:

```
SELECT 
    a.PLUCODE as [Code],
    a.ITEMNAME as [Item],  
    sum(Case When Yr=2012 Then a.janQTY Else 0 End) AS [2012 QTY],
    sum(Case When Yr=2012 Then a.janAmt Else 0 End) AS [2012 AMT],  
    sum(Case When Yr=2013 Then a.janQTY Else 0 End) AS [2013 QTY],
    sum(Case When Yr=2013 Then a.janAmt Else 0 End) AS [2013 AMT],  
FROM (
    Select 2012 As Yr, * From 2012_Table 
 UNION ALL
    Select 2013 As Yr, * From 2013_Table
      ) a  
WHERE a.CATEGORY='Category1'  
GROUP BY a.PLUCODE,a.ITEMNAME 
ORDER BY a.PLUCODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only filtering table A by Category, if PLUCodes are repeated across categories, you are including *all* records with the specified PLU on the right side of the JOIN.  To see what's happening, remove the SUM aggregations and the GROUP BY clause, then include A.Category and B.Category.